# Why won't this print any integers?

Tags: java

```
try {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("testing.txt"));

    while (sc.hasNextInt()){
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        //timing.add(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }   

    sc.close();

}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The text file does have int and strings in it.  I can get it to print words from the text file, but not the numbers.

The text file includes the following:

> Michael 3000
>  7000 Bilbo
>  I like the number 2000 do you?
>  No,
>   I like 9000

Comment: Example of the file you are scanning ?

Comment: Add the contents of your txt file.

Comment: What does it print? Do you have an exception? What is the content of `testing.txt`?

Comment: Michael 3000
7000 Bilbo
I like the number 2000 do you?
No, I like 9000

Comment: That's what is in the testing.txt file

Comment: You could try System.out.println("" + i);, which will force the system to convert the int to a string along the way.

Comment: @durbnpoisn this is unnecessary. The method `println(...)` is overloaded and accepts any primitive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first value ("Michael") *isn't* an integer, therefore it never gets inside of the body of the loop.

Perhaps you want to change the code to loop until it reaches the end of the file, reading and printing integers, but consuming (without printing) non-integer values. So something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
            } else {
                // Just consume the next token
                sc.next();
            }
        }           
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do.  However I'm not entirely sure how to do so.

Comment: You can simply take `sc.next()` and use a `try-catch` to parse an `int` out of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are checking for an `int` first. There is not an `int` first so it will exit your `while` loop without doing anything:

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()){

Michael 3000
```

Michael is not an `int` it is a `String` so there is no `hasNextInt()` there is a `hasNext()` and `hasNextLine()`...

What you can do is:

```
while (sc.hasNext()){
    try
    {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: You still use `sc.hasNextInt()` in your while. So this doesn't make much difference right? It still will never enter the while.

Comment: @lvar yup just forgot to change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You never enter your `while` loop. Because the first input `Michael` is not a number.

A solution would be to take `.next()` and use a `try-catch` to parse an `int` out of it:

```
while (sc.hasNext() {
    String input = sc.next();
    try {
         int printInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
         System.out.println(printInt);
    } catch () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `hasNextInt` will return `false` for your initial string token (`"Michael"`), hence your loop will never execute any statement within.

You can parse every line and infer whether the tokens are convertible to integer types instead:

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {

    try {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // nope
    }
}
```

**Will print...**

```
3000
7000
2000
9000
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a mix of words and numbers. When you call `sc.hasNextInt()`, it checks against "Michael", which isn't an `integer`, so it returns `false` and never executes. In this case, you can read the entire line, and split it on spaces. Then check if each word is an `integer` using `regex`. You can also check by using a `try...catch` block and attempting to parse an `integer` inside of that block.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("StackTxtFiles/text.txt"));

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String [] lineSplitArray = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            for(String wordInLine : lineSplitArray){
                if(wordInLine.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(wordInLine));
                }
            }
        }  

        sc.close();
```

Comment: That seems a little convoluted.