# Finding minimum number from user input

Tags: java

I'm very confused as to why this isn't working, would appreciate some help:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int input = in.nextInt();
        while(in.hasNextInt()){
                if(input < min){
                        min=input;
                }
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(min);

    }
}
```

The loop isn't ending for some reason when I enter something other than an int.

[image: Console screenshot]

Comment: Exact question here earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830718/why-wont-this-print-any-integers

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, seems that the inclusion of in.next(); inside the loop fixed it fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

Because it's waiting for the next integer, and will keep reading forever.  One solution is to use getline() and parse the returned string as an integer.  If conversion fails, you'll have to handle it.  If 0-length string is returned, then exit.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to take `.next()` and use a `try-catch` to parse an `int` out of it:

```
while (in.hasNext() {
    String input = in.next();
    try {
         int printInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
         System.out.println(printInt);
    } catch () {}
}
```

Additionally, I think you're forgetting to call `in.nextInt()` inside your `while` loop.